# multiple inputs in native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a project in react native and use "native-base". I want to have inputs like this [image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing to achieve this?

Comment: @SupriyaKalghatgi Bank card number!

Comment: You said "I want to have inputs like this :, then what issue did you face when you tried coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**May be it's helpful for your requirement**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Item, Input } from "native-base";
export default class RoundedTextboxExample extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Container>
    <Header />
    <Content
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        marginTop: 20,
        borderColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 3,
        margin: 2,
        padding: 20
      }}
    >
      <Item rounded style={{ width: "23%", borderColor: "red" }}>
        <Input placeholder="Rounded" />
      </Item>
      <Item rounded style={{ width: "23%" }}>
        <Input placeholder="Rounded" />
      </Item>
      <Item rounded style={{ width: "23%" }}>
        <Input placeholder="Rounded" />
      </Item>
      <Item rounded style={{ width: "23%" }}>
        <Input placeholder="Rounded" />
      </Item>
    </Content>
  </Container>
);
}
}
```

[image: **It's screenshot from my emulator**]

Answer (score 0):

Well thats possible with NativeBase, just give width of your choice to `Item`

The input mentioned in this screenshot is the width value given with each Input

[image]